# How to collect all log files from a folder and its subfolders using Azure Log Analytics agent?

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics, azure-log-analytics-workspace, azure-agent

I'm trying to collect log files from a folder and all its subfolders using Azure Log Analytics Agent. I followed the instructions on this Microsoft Learn page (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/agents/data-sources-custom-logs#add-log-collection-paths-1), but I'm having trouble setting the path to collect logs from all subfolders.

My log files are stored in the following structure:

C:\Logs\20230414.log

C:\Logs\20230415.log

I want to collect all log files under all subfolders within the C/Logs folder. How can I set the path in Azure Log Analytics to achieve this?

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Currently wildcard works only for file name and it doesn't work for folder name. [This](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/149b6238-e425-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f06a4) is the related feature request raised in feedback portal. If interested, upvote it. In general, Azure product or feature team would check feasibility of a feature request, prioritize against existing feature backlog, add in roadmap as appropriate and would announce and/or update the related Azure document once a feature request is addressed.